# Append whole list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement lazy load in a hybrid app where in i am retrieving some value from database and storing it in a jquery template and displaying it in a list view.

Now i added these below codes for lazyload

```
function addMore(page) {
$.mobile.loading("show", {
    text: "loading more..",
    textVisible: true,
    theme: "b"
});
setTimeout(function () {
    //var items = $("#limsglist").val();
    var items ='A';
    $("#divName", page).append(items).listview("refresh");
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
}, 500);
}
/* scroll event */
 $(document).on("scrollstop", function (e) {
 var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    console.log("adding...");
    addMore(activePage);
 });
```

Now my jquery template looks somewhat like this,

```
 $("#templateName").tmpl(result.Values).appendTo("#divName")
```

List view some what looks like this.

```
  <ul data-role="listview" id="divName"></ul>
    <script type="text/html" id="templateName">
<li class="ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child bgwhite btxt"  id="listName"">
            <img src="../Img" class="chat">
            <h2 class="s txtcap" bottom:5px;">${value1} </h2>
            <p >${value2}</p>
        </li>       

   </script>
```

So Now in place of `$("#divName", page).append(items).listview("refresh");`
items,i want that entire list to be displayed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Seems like template is missing looping syntax but otherwise it's not clear what your problem is or what should happen differently.

Comment: Simple in place of items='A', I need to display the entire list shown above.

Comment: Where does `result.Values` come from? What is happening when you use the `appendTo` that uses it?

Comment: ` $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_files/displayMessage.php',
        type: 'post',
         data: $("#messageBoard").serialize(),       
         success: function(data){
          var result=$.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: so are you using the template inside success callback? If so what isn't working?

Comment: I am trying to use lazyload so that if there are around 200 values i need to display 6 at a moment and after some time out another 6 and so on,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71668/discussion-between-shreyas-tg-and-charlietfl).